# fancybox img as a link, with rel

Tags: image, fancybox

I've a little problem.

I want to use fancybox with imgs only without a tags...

This runs good, but fancybox doesn't make a group with them..

Here my JS and HTML

```
<img rel="group" src="assets/images_portfolio/img1.jpg">

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".work_img img").each(function(){
        $(this).fancybox({
            'padding'   : 0,
            href : $(this).attr('src')
        }); 
    });// end fancybox
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the gallery dynamically since the `rel` won't work on `img` tags since they would be treated as `inline` content so:

```
var gallery = [];
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".work_img img").each(function (i) {
        gallery.push($(this).attr("src"));
        $(this).on("click", function () {
            $.fancybox(gallery, {
                padding: 0,
                index: i // starts gallery from clicked element
            });
        });
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j049g9h9/)**